# child divs don't all appear in parent container

Tags: html, flexbox

why when giving a display: flex and a justify-content: center, the child items don't all appear in the parent div?

I have 15 child divs
HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="dv">1</div>
  <div class="dv">2</div>
  <div class="dv">3</div>
  <div class="dv">4</div>
  <div class="dv">5</div>
  <div class="dv">6</div>
  <div class="dv">7</div>
  <div class="dv">8</div>
  <div class="dv">9</div>
  <div class="dv">10</div>
  <div class="dv">11</div>
  <div class="dv">12</div>
  <div class="dv">13</div>
  <div class="dv">14</div>
  <div class="dv">15</div>  
 </div>
```

when giving a justify-content: center the divs at the beginning of the list disappear
css

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 90%;   
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: pre-line; 
  border: 10px solid rgb(70, 70, 199);  
  width: 500px; 
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;  
}
.dv{
  margin: 19px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 90%;    
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  color: black;

  width: 500px; 
  height: 400px;  
}
```

Comment: at some times the list has 15 divs in others 1 div. How to make this list always centralized?

Comment: Just use `justify-content: start; `

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the total width of the child dvs should not exceed that of the containing parent, and in order to handle such cases we use the flex-wrap property

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).